# Dynamic variable name using this in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to create multiple refs for 40 divs without using `React.createRef()`. But I'm unable to create dynamic variable name for my ref. I'm using below code to create ref.

```
const displayXmasTreeParts = () => Array(40).fill().map((el, index) => (
  <div className={`xmasTreePart${randomClass}`} key={`part${index}`} 
     ref={el => [this.el`${index}`] = el}/>
);

const handleClick = () => this.el5.classList.add(`new-class`);

render() {
  return (
    <div className="xmasTree">
      {this.displayXmasTreeParts()}
    </div>
    <button className="SetUpTree" onClick={this.handleClick}>Click here to reveal Our Xmas Tree</button>
)}
```

I also tried this `` ref={el => `this.el${index}` = el} ``

But getting this error `Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression` in both cases.

Comment: You need to use `[ ]` brackets for dynamic variable names instead of dot

Comment: Do u mean ```this[`${el + index}`] ```? I tried this too but unable to get the value of `this.el5`

Comment: Are you using a functional component? They don't really have an instance you can refer to, certainly not via `this`. How/when/where is `displayXmasTreeParts` called? Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: why don't you store the refs in array ?!

Comment: I'm using Class Component. displayXmasTreeParts() is called from render() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
ref={el => {this["el"+index] = el}}/>
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine to create dynamic variable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to store the refs in array

```
class Component {
    
    let _refs = [];
    
    displayXmasTreeParts = () => Array(40).fill().map((el, index) => {
    
        _refs = [];
    
        return (
           <div className={`xmasTreePart${randomClass}`} key={`part${index}`} 
                ref={el => _refs.push(el)}/>
           );
    }
    
    
    ...

    
}
```

Comment: But is there a way we can have dynamic variable name which has this keyword?

Comment: I don't know about dynamic variables, but I think having an array is a better data structure for your case